# Expression for the metric on a "shifted" manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors, submanifold

Suppose we have an isometric immersion $f:(M^m,g)\to N^{n}$ and let $\{\nu_\alpha\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $TM^\perp$. If we "shift" the manifold in the directions of $\nu_\alpha$ by real (sufficiently small) numbers $z^\alpha$, that is, for every local chart $(U,\phi)$ for $M$ we define the chart $(U,\phi_z)$ for $M_z$ by $$\phi_z=\phi+z^\alpha\nu_\alpha,$$ can we say anything about the metric $g_z$ of $M_z$ as a function of $g$ and $z$?

When $N=\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ there is a known formula stating that
$$
(1)\quad\quad g_z=g(I-zA)^2
$$
where the above expression is in matrix notation and $A$ is the representative matrix of the second fundamental form of $f$. Is there any similar result in higher codimension?

Comment: As written, your proposed mapping appears not to be geometric, but to depend on the choice of ambient coordinates...? This can be rectified by using geodesic coordinates normal to a hypersurface $M$, and there should be a formula in terms of the ambient curvature and second fundamental form of $M$. <> Separately, in codimension greater than $1$ there is not a unique way to "push" $M$ in a normal direction, so one expects a correspondingly more complicated formula involving a choice of normal field.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Yes, I see that the part where I define $\phi_z$ has the issue you pointed out. On the other hand, I didn't get how you suggested to adjust it: I don't think I'm familiar with a concept of geodetic coordinate which is normal to $M$. Do you have any suggestion of any reference where I can find more informations?

Comment: The idea is analogous to ordinary geodesic normal coordinates, but in the normal bundle to $M$: Use geodesics with initial unit velocity normal to $M$ to define coordinates in a sufficiently small tube neighborhood of $M$. (In fancier terms, this is the restriction of the Riemannian exponential map of $N$ to the normal bundle of $M$.) That is, given a local unit normal field $v$ and a sufficiently small scalar $z$, we send a point $x$ of $M$ to the point at signed distance $z$ on the geodesic through $x$ with initial velocity $v$.

Comment: Many thanks, this is definitely a more elegant way to see it!

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, in this case we would have $M_z=\{\exp_p(z^\alpha\nu_\alpha)\ :\ p\in M\}$? Is there a natural way to equip this with a metric?

Comment: If we move $M$ inside $N$, then yes, there's an induced metric on $M$. <> One difference between a hypersurface and a higher-codimension manifold is that a real number (or a real-valued function) is enough to specify how to move a hypersurface if we're given a unit normal field, but in higher codimension we need a normal vector field, not just a constant vector of coefficients, even if we have an orthonormal frame. That is, your $M_{z}$ doesn't just depend on $z$, it depends on the frame fields $(\nu_{\alpha})$.